# Emit a new item if there is a gap since the previous item in the stream

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have a stream of outgoing messages. They can occur at arbitrary intervals. If there is no message for a period after the last message was sent, I'd like to emit a new message which acts as a keep-alive or heartbeat.

[image: marbles diagram]

Here's a code example of what I tried. Suppose I'd like to emit a heartbeat message every 1s after "C" until "D".

```
Flux.concat(
        Flux.just("A", "B", "C").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500)),
        Flux.just("D").delaySequence(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    )
    .windowTimeout(1, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .flatMap(window -> window.switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("*")))
    .log()
    .blockLast();
```

Here's the output

```
14:30:14.659 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(A)
14:30:15.162 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(B)
14:30:15.663 [parallel-4] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(C)
14:30:16.664 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(*)
14:30:17.665 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(*)
14:30:18.664 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(*)
14:30:19.670 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(*)
14:30:20.665 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(*)
14:30:20.676 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(D)
14:30:20.677 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(*)    // Why?
14:30:20.679 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onComplete()
```

In this example, D follows C by 5.013 seconds even though I specified 5 seconds, so I'm not bothered if there are 4 or 5 items/heartbeats emitted in-between.  It doesn't need to be that precise.

But why is there another item omitted after D? Is there a way to fix it? Perhaps I'm using the wrong operation.

I suppose I can achieve it using a processor, but [the documentation says](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_do_i_need_a_processor)

> Most of the time, you should try to avoid using a Processor.

Comment: @tobias_k I can understand the race condition between D and the heartbeat immediately *preceding* D, and in that case I don't really care (can probably just expand the window duration with some arbitrary buffer). But not for one following D

Comment: Oh, I did not see that those two were within the same second.